# Need help with background and button colours

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd

[image]

Using magento 1.9. My own version of the RWD theme.

If you notice there is still a white bar at the left and right after changing the background colour of my main container and my footer.

Any idea what I should be looking for in my CSS to also change the white bars at the sides to a different color? Also I would love to know how to do the same at the top right with my account and cart buttons, and search bar. Thanks

Comment: add your backgorund colour to body tag

Comment: @AhmedElawadi that didn't actually work

Comment: do you have this site live? can you share link

Comment: It's private as I don't want it available til launch, any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Magento platform specifically and can be better answered at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Oli did this work for you, @Prateek I agree with you

Comment: I am new to the forum so I apologise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RWD background added to `.wrapper` class so you need to change it in here :

```
/* ============================================ *
 * Global
 * ============================================ */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

The header links are :

```
/* -------------------------------------------- *
 * Skip - Link
 */
.skip-link {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 44px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #636363;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And the search add background to #search or if you want to change the background for all inputs add it to `.input-text`

*Anther advice if you are on Chrome you can hover on the element you want to change, right click and select inspect element. I use firebug on firefox.*